# Execute a command on the server and send the result to the client in Windows

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm writing a simple server program that executes a command and sends the result to the client. I read countless examples that involve using `popen()`, `pipe()`, `dup2()`, `fork()`, etc., but none of them worked for me and they didn't explain the code very well. I also tried to do it myself, but without success. Could you please provide me with a well documented example?

Here's the code that receives commands/messages from the client:

```
void server_receive() {
    struct sockaddr_in from;
    int from_len, recv_len;
    char buf[BUFLEN], path[256]; // BUFLEN = 1024

    // Getting the path for the command to execute
    strcpy(path, getenv("SYSTEMDRIVE"));
    strcat(path, "\\WINDOWS\\System32\\tasklist.exe");

    from_len = sizeof(from);

    memset(buf, '\0', BUFLEN);
    // Receiving the command
    // I'll add some if-else statements to handle various commands, but for
    // now I just need to see if I can even get one to work.
    if((recv_len = recvfrom(sockt, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &from, &from_len)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("[ERROR] recvfrom() failed: %d.\n\n", WSAGetLastError());
    } else {
        printf("Packet received from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(from.sin_addr), ntohs(from.sin_port));
        printf("Data: %s\n\n", buf);
        // Code to execute tasklist (I used _popen())
        // and send everything back to the client (I used TransmitFile())
    }
}
```

And here's the code that sends commands/messages to the server:

```
void client_send(char server[], unsigned short port) {
    struct sockaddr_in to;
    int s, to_len = sizeof(to);
    char buf[BUFLEN]; // BUFLEN = 1024
    char message[BUFLEN];

    memset((char*) &to, 0, sizeof(to));
    to.sin_family = AF_INET;
    to.sin_port = htons(port);
    to.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr(server);

    while(true) {
        printf("Enter message: ");
        gets(message);

        if (sendto(sockt, message, strlen(message), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &to, to_len) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("[ERROR] sendto() failed: %d.\n\n" , WSAGetLastError());
        }

        memset(buf, '\0', BUFLEN);
        if (recvfrom(sockt, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &to, &to_len) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("[ERROR] recvfrom() failed: %d.\n\n", WSAGetLastError());
        } else {
            printf("Server's response: %s\n\n", buf); /* The result of tasklist
            should be outputted by this line of code, however I'm concerned about the
            relatively small receive length (BUFLEN = 1024).*/
        }
    }
}
```

Needless to say that these two functions are just a part of my code.

Comment: [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499.aspx). You will have to redirect the input/output of tasklist.exe, then you can read commands from the client and send them to the process, and then read its responses and send them back to the client.

Answer (score 1):

That you mention `_popen` (with the leading underscore) and `TransmitFile` indicates that you are on Windows, which doesn't have `fork` or `pipe` or related functions.

There are many alternatives to executing commands in Windows. One is through [`_popen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b.aspx) as you already mentioned (but you don't say what's wrong with that method). Others include the "classic" [`system`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz.aspx) CRT function. And of course the Windows native [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) function. If you want to open a "document" there's the [`ShellExecute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

Knowing which functions are available will help you in your search for examples. Adding the term `windows` to your searches will help finding Windows-specific examples and tutorials. And adding the term `msdn` will help finding topics on the [Microsoft Developer Network](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx).